# Oracle fetch XML from BLOB

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have tried lots of methods and still can't get my full XML document from DB. What I want to achieve is displaying the XML in Oracle Apex (Display only element) but I can't manage to get the full XML out from my blob.

```
SELECT 
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(<blob_column>, 2000, 1))
FROM 
    <my_table> 
WHERE <some_id> = 123
```

Also tried to fetch it with mimetype but had no luck. Thank you.

Comment: You're only retrieving 2000 bytes from your blob column. Why not just do something like `select xmltype(<blob_column>) from <your_table> ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't convert it to `varchar` on the server side since Oracle SQL has a 4K limitation on a `varchar` string size. You can utilize a PL\SQL block for retrieving your data but in this case you will have a limitation in 32K. There is a special way how to get round this issue: http://mayo-tech-ans.blogspot.com/2013/06/displaying-large-clobs-in-oracle-apex.html .

Comment: Didn't worked for me because I had Blob not Clob and I converted from blob to clob. Thanks for the Hint . I posted my answer down.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping, I understood the question correctly.

I think, below query will help you.

1. First, convert the `blob` column to `XMLTYPE`, this will also help to check, if XML is valid or not.
   http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_to_xml_type.htm
2. Then, use `EXTRACTVALUE` to fetch the data from the XML.

   ```
   select EXTRACTVALUE(xml_data,'/note/to')
   from
   (
   select XMLTYPE.createXML('<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Test body</body>
   </note>') xml_data from dual
   )
   ;
   ```

Comment: Didn't knew the element names and this is why I haven't used it like this .

Comment: @AdrianNicolae Ok just posted the query in case you also want to extract data from the XML column.

Comment: Thank you @Tajinder , I will also use your answer for a further step .

Answer (score 0):

In order to get full BLOB content:

1. Converted BLOB into CLOB

> ```
> create or replace FUNCTION blob_to_clob (blob_in IN BLOB)
> RETURN CLOB
> AS
>      v_clob    CLOB;
>      v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
>      v_start      PLS_INTEGER := 1;
>      v_buffer  PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
> BEGIN
>      DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE);
>
>      FOR i IN 1..CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_in) / v_buffer)
>      LOOP
>
>         v_varchar := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_in, v_buffer, v_start));
>
>            DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob, LENGTH(v_varchar), v_varchar);
>
>           v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
>      END LOOP;
>
>    RETURN v_clob;
>
> END blob_to_clob;
> ```

2. In Oracle Apex created Display Only (element) called ex: P5_XML
3. PLSQL code

> ```
> declare
>     v_clob    clob;
> begin
>     SELECT blob_to_clob(<blob_column>) INTO v_clob FROM <table> WHERE <some_column> = <something>;
>     :P5_XML := v_clob;
> end;
> ```